# Python R/W to text file network

Tags: python, process

What could happen if multiple users run the same copies of python script which designed to R/W data to a single text file store in network device at the same time?

Will the processes stop working?

If so, what could be the solution?

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors. Are you actually experiencing processes dying? Is there an error message? (The general solution is "don't do that, use a database")

Comment: What type of database would you suggest?SQLite? Bear with me, i am a beginner.

Comment: SQLite is designed for local storage, is just a file in the filesystem, so I'm not completely sure it will work well in a network environment, you can use MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can happen many bad things, I don't think the processes stop working, not at least because of concurrent access to file a file, but what could happen is and **inconsistent file creation:** for example, if one processes write `hello`, and there is a concurrent access to the file, you might get a line like `hhelllolo`

A solution I can see is, use a database as suggested, or, create a mechanism for locking the file to concurrent accesses (which might be cumbersome because you're working on network, not the same computer)

Another solution I can think of is create a server side simple script who handle the requests and lock the file for concurrent access. This is almost the same solution as using a database, you'll be creating an storage system from scratch so why bother :)

Hope this helps!